# I wrote a matrix into a file. How do I read this matrix from this file in Mathmatica11?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

for example,

`m1.txt
1 2 3
4 5 6`

now, I want to read this file, and get a matrix

`m={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}`

What should I do?

Comment: `m = Import["m1.txt", "Table"]`

Comment: This can be closed because it is adequately answered by a comment

Answer (score 0):

See Bill's comment about using `Import`, or you could literally have the line

```
m = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

in m1.txt, and then use `` <<"m1.txt`"; `` to run the contents of m1.txt as Mathematica code.